# Fluctuation of GPS Altitude stops when second app is running

Tags: android, gps, fusedlocationproviderclient, altitude

I have developed an Android app for recording (paraglider) flights and the altitude recording from (GPS-) location data is usually fine.
But now I got a complaint that the recorded altitude is fluctuating heavily. (Android 10 on Pixel 3a)
The strange thing is, that (according to the users observation) the recording is smooth again, if another sports tracker is running in addition. So it seems that the way, the other sports tracker is using location data also smooths the location data for my app.
I am using FusedLocationProvider and think I have already set the highest possible quality:

```
       FusedLocationProviderClient client = LocationServices
                .getFusedLocationProviderClient(ctx);
        LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
        request.setInterval(1000); //Every second
        request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        client.requestLocationUpdates(request, provideLocationCallback(), null);
```

One guess would be, that the FusedLocation is sometimes created from a different source than GPS and therefore the lat/lon is fine, but the altitude is "wrong". But how does the other app influence the location provider in such a way, that it is returning GPS-Locations only?
Or in other words, how can I force myself the location provider to deliver only GPS locations?

Comment: Then just use the gps only. You can program that. Why would you need more? What would be the other one high in the sky?

Comment: I changed to FusedLocationProvider because of the information given here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits But maybe changing to ForegroundService only would have been sufficient.

Comment: For your use case a ForgroundService sounds the right thing to do.  You may also want to look at using the pressure sensor if there is one as that generally allows far better altitude than GPS although you need to work at the calibration.  You may have strange wind effects in your use case though.